# Barcode scanner for phonegap android is not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

Hello am using barcode plugin from the following link  - https://github.com/jonathannaguin/BarcodeScanner

I am able to run the app but if I click on scan, it says not found error in the below line

```
var scanner = cordova.require("com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner");
```

So can you please help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your link is not correct. Can you update the link. And have you added the plugin in your config.xml file?

Comment: That sounds like your application is not being able to see the plugin. Have you added the plugin correctly?

Comment: have used `cordova plugins add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git`

Comment: And I have added following line in config.xml file `<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner"/>`

Comment: "Uncaught module com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner not found", source: file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js